# How to append the date to a string in bash

Tags: bash, date, raspberry-pi

I have a script that backups my Raspberry Pi

```
sudo dd bs=1M if=/dev/sda1 of=/home/pi/backup.img
zip -r /home/pi/backup/backup.zip /home/pi/backup.img
cp backup.zip ~/backup
```

I want to know how I can append the date to the backup.zip file, generated by the second line.

Any tips?

Comment: Does /home/pi live on /dev/sda1?  If it does, there is precisely zero chance that this will give you a usable backup.  I would imagine that doesn't make any sense, since writing a disk's own image to that disk is probably always impossible, but unless you're making sure nothing can write to /dev/sda1 (i.e. by mounting it read only, or unmounting it completely) there's a very real chance that some in-progress file IO will leave your image in an inconsistent state.

Comment: @Wug - Out of curiosity, what's the worst that could happen?  Any files being written at the time could be backed up in an invalid state, but is that the extent of bad stuff that could happen?  Exactly how bad is that?

Comment: For example: the inode table in EXT FSs tends to be contiguous, and near the beginning of the FS.  Say you copy the whole disk.  As the copy run, you delete a file and create a new one.  Your already-copied inode table still remembers the original file, but your bulk copy hadn't made it that far yet, and by the time it gets to that file's blocks, they've been de- and re-allocated to the other file, which has scribbled all over them.  oops!  Remove a folder instead and you end up with corrupt directory entries.  It's a whole world of horribleness.

Comment: Worse things can end up happening if you somehow do something in the (very short) windows between copying the inode table and the free block bitmap.  You can end up with files containing unallocated blocks, blocks that are allocated but to no files, directories that contain files that don't exist, etc etc...

Comment: @Wug - Good to know.  Wouldn't it also be physically impossible to fit a backup of a device on itself?  For example, if `/dev/sda1` is 8 GB, then wont the dump be 8 GB and impossible to fit on `/dev/sda1` unless it was 100% empty?

Comment: @Mr.Llama I modified the script to put it in a shared folder, which is then put on my laptop.

Comment: @Mr.Llama: I realized the absurdity of that situation as I was typing the first comment, and in this situation it would be impossible, but it's possible to fit a backup of a drive on the drive itself if, for example, you compress it.  I don't know why you'd ever do that, but it's possible.

Comment: @Wug, yeah I dont know how it is possible, but I was able to fit the backup on the drive and then `mv` it into my shared folder. That was before I put it into a script and I was just using `dd`. I also added the rsync command to the script, just in case all I needed was a single file.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use [command substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html) to accomplish this.
You might also want to familiarize yourself with the [`date`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?date) components:

```
# Save the file name in a variable so we don't repeat ourselves
outfile="/home/pi/backup/backup.zip.$(date +%Y%m%d)"

sudo dd bs=1M if=/dev/sda1 of=/home/pi/backup.img
zip -r "${outfile}" /home/pi/backup.img
cp "${outfile}" ~/backup
```

The magic here is the `$(date +%Y%m%d)`.  This runs `date +%Y%m%d` and captures the output which will be the current date in YYYYMMDD format.

Comment: You probably want `.../backup.$(date ...).zip`